# GDB: I have the address of a static variable, how do I get the file name that defines it?

Tags: gdb, filenames, debug-symbols

(gdb) x/x &Memory_PageSize        <= this is a global variable
0x84b32d0 <_ZL15Memory_PageSize>:       0x00000001

gdb finds my global variable, but which file?

I work on a large project w/lots of #ifdef's. Variables can be defined in multiple places but only one is compiled in.  I want to use gdb to quickly find the correct source file to avoid grep, thx.

I tried '(gdb) info line ' but it only works on functions, not global variables

(gdb) info line 0x84b32d0
Function "0x84b32d0" not defined

(gdb) info line myTest   <= this works great on functions but not my global variable
Line 2552 of "test.cxx"

Comment: How about `info var Memory_PageSize`?

Comment: 'info var Memory_PageSize' has been running for over 10 minutes with no sign of stopping.  It's frustrating because 'info line <funcname>' and  'x/x &Memory_PageSize' return instantly.

So it can find the var name and print out the value instantly but not the line number.

Comment: If it really never stops, then it's probably a gdb bug. Are you using the latest gdb version?

Comment: Using "8.3.1 2019-08 2019-09 2019-09-20"
The CPU churns away, I was wondering if 'info var' has to scan the symbol table instead of do a hash lookup.  I don't know, just guessing about that.